# Get Flux size when Flux is complete

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I'm kinda stuck with a trivial task: whenever I query an external API with reactive spring WebClient or query reactive MongoDBRepository, I'd like to log how many entities got through my flux, eg. to log message like "Found n records in the database.". Eg:

```
return repository.findAll()
                 .doOnComplete { log.info("Found total n records!") } // how to get the n?
                 .filter { it.age > 10 }
                 .distinct { it.name }
```

TLDR: How to get a flux size (and perhaps it's contents) when it completes?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [ConnectableFlux](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#advanced-broadcast-multiple-subscribers-connectableflux). In your example:

```
var all = repository.findAll()
             .filter { it.age > 10 }
             .distinct { it.name }
             .publish()
             .autoConnect(2)

all.count()
   .subscribe {c -> log.info("Found total {} records!", c)}

return all;
```

Answer (score 4):

By calling the [count()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#count--). It should emit a Mono when onComplete is observed.

Comment: Ok, that brings me closer, but after that operation leaves me with Mono<Long?> while I'd like to process further operations on the Flux leaving it unchanged. In other words, I'd like to subscribe to onComplete of the flux with having this count.

Comment: Understood. You could possibly keep the count yourself (increment as you receive items). I can't think of a better way; please update if you find out.

Answer (score -2):

Here was what I did,

```
AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger();
Flux<UserDetails> stringFlux =
                Flux.using(() -> stringStream, Flux::fromStream,
                Stream::close)
                        .doOnNext(s -> i.getAndIncrement())
                        .log()
                        .map(UserDetails::createUserDetails);

stringFlux
                .subscribe(updateUserDetailsService::updateUserDetails);

log.info("number of records: {}", i);
```